# seeking algorithm: get parameter from specific url structure

Tags: algorithm, url, parameters

For example  ://param1/p1/param2/p2/param3/p3/
then get {param1:p1,param2:p2, param3:p3 }
however, param1 param2 param3 may not be there at the same time, there might be ://param1/p1  or ://param1/p1/param2/p2

Currently, I split the url by param1, param2, param3, and then use if() to get p1 p2 p3, but there are too many if().  I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

My Python code for this -

```
s = '://param1/p1/param2/p2/param3/p3/'

s = s[3:]

arr = s.split('/')

d = {k : v for k, v in zip(arr[0::2], arr[1::2])}

print(d)
```

Output :

```
{'param1': 'p1', 'param2': 'p2', 'param3': 'p3'}
```